# Where are the Android Users and Groups?

Tags: permissions, android

Android uses a linux kernel with each installed app getting its own user.

I was expecting to find them in /etc/passwd but I couldn't.

Where are they stored?

Answer (score 9):

I think it's here.

```
/data/system/packages.list
```

Comment: How about system users/groups?